# Is there a way to export citation in text using R?

Tags: r, export

I have a list of urls of research articles (~ 80). I want to add their citation text in the bibliograhy in APA format. Is there a way to automate this in R?

I have tried with `ReadCrossRef()` function in `RefManageR` package. But it gives an incomplete citation which is not in APA format.